# Java springboot websocket , no connection between browser and server

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I implemented the Spring webSocket example like described on the page:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

But in my case it doesn't work. On the html page where the request is sent, the response is not displayed.
What I read from other articles is that once a connection is established, the following message appears in the browser DevTools in the Console Tab:  "<<< CONNECTED...."
This message is not appearing at all in my case, and this must be he reason of the Problem.
As I copied the example 1 to 1, I can really see what could be the cause the connection not working.

Probably I made an mistake somewhere, but I don't find my mistake.

**GreetingController.java**

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()) + "!");
    }
}
```

**WebSocketConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

**app.js**

```
var stompClient = null;

function setConnected(connected) {
    $("#connect").prop("disabled", connected);
    $("#disconnect").prop("disabled", !connected);
    if (connected) {
        $("#conversation").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#conversation").hide();
    }
    $("#greetings").html("");
}

function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/gs-guide-websocket');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function (greeting) {
            showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
        });
    });
}

function disconnect() {
    if (stompClient !== null) {
        stompClient.disconnect();
    }
    setConnected(false);
    console.log("Disconnected");
}

function sendName() {
    stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify({'name': $("#name").val()}));
}

function showGreeting(message) {
    $("#greetings").append("<tr><td>" + message + "</td></tr>");
}

$(function () {
    $("form").on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $( "#connect" ).click(function() { connect(); });
    $( "#disconnect" ).click(function() { disconnect(); });
    $( "#send" ).click(function() { sendName(); });
});
```

[image: Browser DEVTools]

[image: Console]

[image: Network Tab from browser]

[image: Network Tab from browser (Messages)]

Comment: Hi, can you add screen with network tab from browser?

Comment: I've added the Network Tab from the browser.  There is popup which indicates "Stalled 10.23 s".  Could this be the reason ?

Comment: One more question, as i see, you use 5000 port, is it correct port of springboot app?

Comment: I changed the port number from 8080 to 5000.  But that can't be the reason because when I enter localhost:5000 , the page index.html is loaded correctly.

Comment: I modified the title and the description. This because I found out that there is no connection established at all.  In the browser there should be a message  " <<< CONNECTED .... "  And this message is missing in my case.

Comment: I try this project from repo and it's work on my local machine. Did you change something in code?

Comment: I copied all the code from the webpage. So, it should be the same.  From what repo did you download the code ?

Comment: I found the link to the code....will download it from there and try again.

Comment: I've downloaded the code from the repo, and it works indeed !  Many thanks for the hint. Now I'll search for the differences.